# Is there a difference between -뜹니다 and -씁니다?

Tags: polite, formal

I recently came across the verb 고맙다 conjugated as follows: 고맙뜹니다

I was confused, as I've never seen the formal polite ending spelled with ㄸ. Usually it's spelled -습니다.

I checked verbix.com and couldn't find this verb ending listed.

Is this a misspelling or a real verb ending?

Thanks.

Comment: In my memory, 고맙뜹니다 is used by comedians to obtain people's smile, since it can be viewed as an imitation of a stupid man's pronunciation.

Comment: Can you please post a link to where you came across this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm a korean.
-뜹니다. is not formal expression.
If someone want to show cuteness, the word goes like that.
like 'ㅃ', 'ㄸ', 'ㅉ' pronunciation, These consonant sound 'cute' to korean.
So they use these expression frequently with their friends.
(The Purpose of using these expression is so various.
With good manner, wife use these wording her husband with love.
Or Ridicule someone, or just kidding ...)

There are so many examples.
1) '그랬어요?' -> '그랬쬬요?', '구랬쬬요?' (You do~?)
2) '알겠음' -> '알겠뜸' (I see)
3) '~할거야' -> '~할꾸얌' (I will do~)

Additionally...This case is one of the reasons why korean language is hard to be processed to NLP